# unit testing a react component with `ua-parser-js` plugin in jest and react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, ua-parser

I've create a very simple component which shows an image based on the os you are on (in my case iOS and Android)

```
import { UAParser } from "ua-parser-js";

export const DownloadApp = ({ appleStoreUrl, playStoreUrl }: DownloadAppProps): JSX.Element => {
  const parser = new UAParser();
  const os = parser.getOS();

return (<div className="flex h-12">
        {os.name === "iOS" && (
          <div>
            <a href={appleStoreUrl} title="Apple App Store">
              <AppleAppStore height="48" />
            </a>
          </div>
        )}

        {(os.name === "Android" || os.name === "Android[-x86]") && (
          <div className="shrink">
            <a href={playStoreUrl} title="Google Play Store">
              <GooglePlayStore height="48" />
            </a>
          </div>
        )}
</div>)}
```

This all works great when manually testing on devices but I'm trying to write some unit tests in `react-testing-library` and `jest` to check that the correct image is shown based on the OS response.

I've tried mocking the `ua-parser-js` library but I always need to instantiate the library to get the `getOS()` function of which I want to set a mockImplementation to return iOS and Android but it seems to totally ignore the mock and just calls the `ua-parser-js` package and returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mocking ua-parser-js there is the option of mocking the userAgent getter with jest. With this approach you can then use whatever user agent you like to match your test scenario.

In your beforeEach:

```
const userAgentGetter = jest.spyOn(window.navigator, 'userAgent', 'get')
userAgentGetter.mockReturnValue('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.1 Safari/605.1.15')
```

In your afterEach:

```
jest.restoreAllMocks()
```